# How do i do an SELECT in an INSERT?

Tags: .net, sqlite

I want to do something like this

```
INSERT INTO link_list(link, status, hash_type, hash_id)
VALUES(@link, @status, @hash_type, @hash_id);
INSERT INTO active_dl(fileId, orderNo)
VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), SELECT COUNT(*) FROM active_dl);
```

But obviously it is wrong and theres a syntax error on select. How do i write this? Using sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the SELECT query in <strike>brackets</strike> parenthesis.

Like so:

```
INSERT INTO active_dl(fileId, orderNo)
VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM active_dl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
DECLARE @var INT
SET @var = (Select Count(*) from active_dl)

INSERT INTO active_dl(fileId, orderNo)
VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), @var);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried maybe:

```
...
VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM active_dl)); <--- with parens
```

I don't claim to know sqlite, but maybe this could help

Answer (score 0):

I believe standard SQL lets you use *either* `values` or `select` for an `insert`, so I'd be looking at:

```
insert into active_dl(fileId, orderNo)
    select last_insert_rowid(), COUNT(*) FROM active_dl;
```

Whether SQLite allows this I don't know for sure, hence the community wiki.